# line anchor behavior with perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I recently wrote a little Perl script to trim whitespace from the end of lines and ran into unexpected behavior.  I decided that Perl must include line-end characters when breaking up lines, so tested that theory and got even more unexpected behavior.  `I do not` should either match `\s+$` or `t$`...Not both.  Very confused.  Can anyone enlighten me?

```
£ cat example
I have space after me
I do not
£ perl -ne 'print if /\s+$/' example
I have a space after me
I do not
£ perl -ne 'print if /t$/' example
I do not
£
```

PCRE tester gives expected results.  I've also tried the `/m` suffix with no change in behavior.

edit.  for completeness:

```
£ perl -ne 'print if /e$/' example
£
```

Expected behavior from `perl -ne 'print if...'` was the same as `grep -P`:

```
£ grep -P '\s+$' example
I have a space after me
£
```

Can repro under Ubuntu 16.04 perl v5.22.1 (both 60 and 68 patch version) and MINGW perl v5.26.1.

Comment: Which version of Perl running under what OS environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see your current behavior because in `example` file the second line has `\n` character at the end. `\n` is the space which matched by `\s`

---

[`perlretut`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

> no modifiers: Default behavior. ... '$' matches only at the end or before a newline at the end.

At your regex `\s matches a whitespace character, the set [\ \t\v\r\n\f]`. In other words it matches the spaces and `\n` character. Then `$` matches the end of line (no characters, just the position itself). Like `word anchor \b` matches word boundary, and `^` matches the beginning of the line and not the first character

You could rewrite your regex like this:

```
/[\t ]+$/
```

---

The content of `example` would look like this if second line didn't end with a `\n` character:

```
£ cat example
I have space after me
I do not£
```

NOTICE that shell prompt `£` is not on next line

---

The results are different because `grep` abstracts out line endings like Perl's `-l` flag. (`grep -P '\n'` will return no results on a text file where `grep -Pz '\n'` will.)

Comment: I feel this this does not solve the OP's issue. `perl -ne 'print if /\s+\n?$/' example` gives the same result as the original regex.

Comment: @wp78de: OP has issue because he has `\n` character at the end of second line. And it seems it is a `grep` bug, because second line is not showed. Do you notice that `-P` option is `highly experimental`?

Comment: Nice catch. I wish the OP gave clearer direction whether it is about the unexpected results or solving the problem with the match.

Comment: I did notice the 'highly experimental' but still couldn't figure out how the perl result was correct.  I think the key is that `$` matches both before AND after the \n (because that's the end of the string)

Comment: I accepted this answer because the quote from `perlretut` answered my question, but the proposed regex `\s+\n?$` is incorrect and still returns every line.  `[\t ]+$` works.

Comment: Bonus points if anyone can explain to me why `$` matches at end of string AND at `\n` before end of string?  Does this make for more intuitive behavior in some situations?

Comment: Also I just noticed `-l` caused expected behavior.  I assume this is because perl abstracts line-endings away at this point and it therefore is missing from the scanned string.

Comment: @zzxyz: Imagine next regex: `"abcd\nfgh" =~ /(.*)$/gm`. Here `$`  match after `d` because `\n` mark the end of string. Also it match after `h` because it is physical end of string/text. Another example: `abcd\nfgh\n`. Here three strings: `abcd`, `fgh` and empty string ``. Here `$` match  before `\n` after `d`, before `\n` after `h`, before physical end of line, by coincidence, after `\n` because of empty line. To see what had happened step by step run `perl -Mre=debug -ne 'print if /\s+$/' example`

Comment: @EugenKonkov - I didn't know about `re=debug`.  That's nice.

Comment: @zzxyz: In perl there is many interesting things from the box

Answer (score 2):

Your problems stem from the `-n` option and the use of `\s`. The `-n` flag feeds the input to Perl line by line into `$_`, then it calls the `print if match` statement.

In your match you use the `$` anchor to match the end of the line. The anchor is purely positional and does not consume the newline or any other character.

Check it yourself [here](https://regex101.com/r/PJMuvO/1) with `\s+`: Whether your add a `$` or not, the regex matches the same number of characters.
This is because `\s` is equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]` and matches any whitespace character and you have added the `+` quantifier. So, it matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible (greedy).

If you searched just for trailing space characters instead you are good: `[ ]+$` (here escaped with a group):

```
£ perl -ne 'print if /[ ]+$/' example
```

That way it does not match the `\n` like `\s` does. Try it yourself [here](https://regex101.com/r/PJMuvO/2).

**Bonus**:

Here are some common Perl one-liners to trim spaces:

```
# Strip leading whitespace (spaces, tabs) from the beginning of each line
perl -ple 's/^[ \t]+//'
perl -ple 's/^\s+//'

# Strip trailing whitespace (space, tabs) from the end of each line
perl -ple 's/[ \t]+$//'

# Strip whitespace from the beginning and end of each line
perl -ple 's/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$//g'
```

Comment: And sorry, my question should've made it clear I found a workaround and was just confused by the behavior.  I ended up using `[ \t]` instead of \s